# How to change an online application to offline using url?

Tags: android

I'm getting data form url which is in json format my app is online now and I want to convert it to offline, So how will I get url from local database? How to make the application offline is it possible to insert all json form url into the database and then fetch it from local database using same query ? My application activities is having the same type classes get data from url. I'm geting data only once then use a local database? In my url there are some  condition with respect to schoolId  school leveled so how will I do this with the local database I'm confused to help me to make my application offline
`{"status":1,"data":[{"title":"Atypical"}]}`

```java
public class MenuGroup extends Activity {

    String status;
    Menugroupscreenadapter mma;
    String SelectMenuAPI;
    String SelectMenuAPI2;
     // String School_name;
    String elementry;
    String schedule_id, semestertitle, start_date, end_date;


    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    TextView txtAlert ,NoMenuAvailable ;
    int IOConnect = 0;
    ListView     listmenusgroups;
    String School_name;
    long School_ID;
    String URL,URL2;
    String SchoolLevelId;
    String menutype;
    TextView Elementarytxt, Middletxt, Hightxt, Atypicaltxt;
    static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
    static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();

    static ArrayList<Long> Menu_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();

    String _response;

    String Elementarytxtview,Middletextview,Hightextview,Atipicaltextview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menugroup);



        Intent iGet = getIntent();




           listmenusgroups = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listmenusgroups);


        mma = new Menugroupscreenadapter(this);
          new getDataTask().execute();



          listmenusgroups.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int position, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent iMenuList = new Intent(MenuGroup.this, thirdstep.class);


                iMenuList.putExtra("Menu_ID", Menu_ID.get(position));
                iMenuList.putExtra("menu_group", Category_name.get(position));




                startActivity(iMenuList);

            }
        });

    }








     public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String>{

            getDataTask(){
                if(!prgLoading.isShown()){


                }
            }

            @Override
             protected void onPreExecute() {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SelectMenuAPI = Utils.menugroups+School_ID+"&lid="+SchoolLevelId+"&menu=no";




                URL = SelectMenuAPI;
                URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");


         try {

            Log.i("url",""+URL2);
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL2); 
             HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
             HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
              _response=EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);






       }

         catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 IOConnect = 1;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 



                          return _response;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                prgLoading.setVisibility(8);


                    listmenusgroups.setVisibility(0);


                    try {




            JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(result);

            status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {



    JSONArray school = json2.getJSONArray("data");

    for (int i = 0; i < school.length(); i++) {

         JSONObject object = school.getJSONObject(i);



               Category_ID.add((long) i);


         Menu_ID.add(Long.parseLong(object.getString("menu_id")));

          Category_name.add(object.getString("menu_title"));

        }

        } 
        else {
        NoMenuAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        NoMenuAvailable.setText("No Menu Available for this School.");
        listmenusgroups.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            }

            } 

        catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
        }else{
        txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }
        listmenusgroups.setAdapter(mma);
            }
        }
```

Comment: this is my online app how i will make it offline????

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file of your data(JSON OR XML) in sdcard at the time of installation,and refer that text file as an input when there is no internet connection.

By following this you can achieve your goal.

```
    File storage = new File("/sdcard/appData/photos");
    storage.mkdirs();

    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1);

    //transforming jsonObject to byte[] and store it
    String jsonString = json.toString();                
    byte[] jsonArray = jsonString.getBytes();

    String filen = "jsonData";
    File fileToSaveJson = new File("/sdcard/appData",filen);

    FileOutputStream fos;
    fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToSaveJson);

    fos = openFileOutput(filen,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(jsonArray);
    fos.close();


    //re

ading jsonString from storage and transform it into jsonObject              
FileInputStream fis;
File readFromJson = new File("/sdcard/appData/jsonData");

fis =  new FileInputStream(readFromJson);

fis =  new FileInputStream(readFromJson);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

fis.read(new byte[(int)readFromJson.length()]);
```

hope this helps...

Comment: how to save  http response data in textfile? give me example what u say  imean working example if u have

Comment: url save json data of which name  jsonData.txt??  what is file name which u save ad this location  "/sdcard/appData/photos"

Comment: yes,it's name is jsonData.txt.....and read this text file at offline and refer it's string as a input to parse....

Comment: but problem is im getting response from server with conditoon like if schoolid  and schoollevel id to filter nad get only spesific data so if i get all data from server and save in local textfile how i will make quiry and get only specific data from textfile??

Comment: if your server response is differ every time then this method is not useful to you...nad i think there is no way to make it offline for differ json/xml value

Comment: but suppose if in my server al school in list from A to Z in online i give school name server return that school detail but if i get all list of school from server at one time and how i will make query locallly???

Comment: if you can get all data once there is no change in online and offline query.online and offline is just matter of json/xml and parsing is same for both

Comment: suppose i have 1 textfile contain list of school which show in listview i select 1 school how i will pass selected school name as parameter to qury that school informationfrom another textfile which contain bulk of school detail??? whatis procedure to make wury with textfile tell me in my code senario which is above i paste